AzCopy Upload Works in CMD but Fails with 403/401 Errors in Batch Script
I am encountering an issue with AzCopy where my script runs perfectly fine in CMD but fails with authentication errors when executed via a batch file. Here's a breakdown of the situation:
The aim is to get our daily files backed up into storage account via task scheduler; most likely only 1 file per day/run.
My Batch Script:
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\AzCopy"
azcopy cp "G:\Backup\UATBackups\*" "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/test/?sp=rw&st=2024-10-08T15:28:58Z&se=2024-10-08T23:28:58Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=<SAS-token>" --recursive=true --block-blob-tier=Cold --overwrite=false

When I Run This Command Manually in CMD: (after navigating to the AzCopy directory)
azcopy cp "G:\Backup\UATBackups\*" "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/test/?sp=rw&st=2024-10-08T15:28:58Z&se=2024-10-08T23:28:58Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=<SAS-token>" --recursive=true --block-blob-tier=Cold --overwrite=false

It works perfectly, and all the files are uploaded as expected.
However, When I Run the Batch File, I Get:
RESPONSE Status: 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

I also tried modifying the batch file so it opens CMD and runs the command as if I was doing it manually:
start cmd /k ""C:\Program Files\AzCopy\azcopy.exe" cp "G:\Backup\UATBackups\*" "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/test/?sp=rw&st=2024-10-08T15:28:58Z&se=2024-10-08T23:28:58Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=<SAS-token>" --recursive=true --block-blob-tier=Cold --overwrite=false"

But this gives me:
RESPONSE 401: 401 Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
ERROR CODE: NoAuthenticationInformation

Things I Have Checked:

The SAS Token is valid and not expired.
The VM time is correctly synced.
I’m using the same user account to run both the CMD and the batch file.

My Question:

Why does the command work perfectly when I run it manually in CMD, but fail with a 403 error when run via a batch file (even using the same user account)?
What needs changing and how do I fix this!

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
